# XSS - Does loading external HTML by setting innerHTML on DOM element prevent attack?

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss, websecurity

If I will need to load some untrusted external HTML content and render them on the DOM, will using the `innerHTML` property be adequate protection against malicious scripts?

Through my own testing and this [article](https://eager.io/blog/everything-I-know-about-the-script-tag/#:%7E:text=As%20you%20probably%20know%2C%20the%20script%20tag%20is,tags%20are%20executed%20in%20the%20order%20they%20appear), `<script>` tags inside HTML that is set via `innerHTML` to an existing element in the DOM (main or shadow) is not executed. So even if the script is there, would not executing it prevent security risks?

For added measure, it can also help to find all `<script>` tags and remove them in the DOM. Is this even necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not good enough. Inline handlers can still execute - most notably, those that'll execute immediately. For example:

```js
const untrustworthyContent = `
<div>
  <img src onerror="alert('evil');">
</div>
`;
document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = untrustworthyContent;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

And anything can be put into such an inline handler attribute, including loading other malicious scripts.

> For added measure, it can also help to find all  tags and remove them in the DOM. Is this even necessary?

Best to do it thoroughly. Remove all `<script>` tags and inline handlers before even thinking about rendering.

Comment: Would adding a CSP header on the HTTP response resolve this issue? From what I read it will prevent all inline scripting. A loophole here is it won't really apply to iframe, but that seems easier to resolve by removing.

Comment: It could, but I wouldn't want to rely on it completely - I'd prefer to make sure the inserted HTML doesn't cause problems no matter where it's inserted, no matter the server configuration.

Comment: Fair, ideally I wouldn't insert untrusted HTML to begin with. Just thinking about if I had to do it, how I might insert it safely. A regex matching and sanitising obviously works but a lot more computation involved. Wondering if there's some other more native ways of doing this?